# how to return values in a goroutine

Tags: go

I have the code:

```
    go s.addItemSync(ch, cs.ResponseQueue, user)
```

This calls the func:

```
func (s *Services) addItemSync(ch types.ChannelInsertion, statusQueueName, user string) {
   //func body here
}
```

I would however like to do this:

```
if ok, err := go s.addItemSync(ch, cs.ResponseQueue, user); !ok {
    if err != nil {
        log.Log.Error("Error adding channel", zap.Error(err))
        return
}
```

Which would change the other func to this

```
func (s *Services) addItemSync(ch types.ChannelInsertion, statusQueueName, user string) (bool, error) {

}
```

As in, I would like to be able to declare a `go func` but this errors out every time. Any idea how you can declare a variable while able to call the `go func` ability for synchronous calls? as seen in the     `if ok, err := go s.addItemSync(ch, cs.ResponseQueue, user); !ok {` line?

Comment: Remove the `go` keyword. You can't launch a goroutine to not wait for it to complete _and_ wait for it to complete (to examine the result) at the same time. If you do want concurrent execution, use a channel to communicate the result.

Comment: Could you add an example for how this would work with a channel @icza ?

Comment: You can wrap the code into an anon func and execute that in a new goroutine https://play.golang.com/p/8Buh9wEM3hM.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to wait until a go-routine has completed, you need to return results in a channel.  The basic pattern, without complicating with wait groups, etc. is:

```
func myFunc() {
    // make a channel to receive errors
    errChan := make(chan error)

    // launch a go routine
    go doSomething(myVar, errChan)

    // block until something received on the error channel
    if err := <- errChan; err != nil {
        // something bad happened
    }
}

// your async funciton
func doSomething(myVar interface{}, errChan chan error) {
    // Do stuff
    if something, err := someOtherFunc(myVar); err != nil {
         errChan <- err
         return
    }

    // all good - send nil to the error channel
    errChan <- nil

}
```

In your case if you just want to fire off a go-routine and log if an error happens, you can use an anonymous function:

```
go func() {
    if ok, err := s.addItemSync(ch, cs.ResponseQueue, user); !ok {
        if err != nil {
            log.Log.Error("Error adding channel", zap.Error(err))
        }
    }
}()
```

Or if you want to wait for the result:

```
errChan := make(chan error)
go func() {
    if ok, err := s.addItemSync(ch, cs.ResponseQueue, user); !ok {
        if err != nil {
            errChan <- err
            return
        }
    }
    errChan <- nil
}()

// do some other stuff while we wait...

// block until go routine returns
if err := <- errChan; err != nil {
    log.Log.Error("Error adding channel", zap.Error(err))
}
```

**Note:**
Your code as written, may have unexpected results if it is possible that a response where `ok == false` would not return an error.  If this is a concern, I would suggest creating and returning a new error for cases where `!ok && err == nil`